# How Templates from Android for car app library addresses layout on multiple devices/infotainment-systems?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-automotive, automotive, android-windowsizeclass-api

We built our Automotive app with custom UI instead of the [templates](https://developer.android.com/static/training/cars/Android%20for%20Cars%20App%20Library%20design%20guidelines.pdf). List of templates available there are not enough to offer the services we want to, to the user. Also our features list does not scale.
Pain with custom UI is that dealing with multiple device form factors. Unlike mobile devices, Infotainment Systems in cars varies a lot from 1:1, 12:16, 20:8, to 30:8. [windowSizeClass](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive) API does not help much.

I am wondering how templates supports rendering on such devices ? They just use the same template/layout on all devices but with varied size of elements or is there any logic that we can also try using in out custom API to address this wide variation of devices ?

Any suggestions about this will be appreciated.

Comment: @ben-sagmoe can you please help if you have any clue or any guidance ?